# An Addition formula for Hermite polynomials

Tags: reference-request, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

My question concerns an addition formula that can be found on the Wikipedia page of [Hermite Polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Recursion_relation) but I can't find it anywhere else. The well-known formula that can be found in many books is the following
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
H_{n}(x+y) &=2^{-{\frac {n}{2}}}\cdot \sum _{k=0}^{n}{\binom {n}{k}}H_{n-k}\left(x{\sqrt {2}}\right)H_{k}\left(y{\sqrt {2}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

The formula  I seek a reference for is the following
$$
H_{n}(x+y) =\sum _{k=0}^{n}{\binom {n}{k}}H_{k}(x)(2y)^{(n-k)}
$$

Can you please point me to a reference where I can find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the generating function for Hermite polynomials
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} H_n(x) \frac{t^n}{n!}=e^{2xt-t^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
 So 
 \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} H_n(x+y) \frac{t^n}{n!}&=&e^{2yt}e^{2xt-t^2} \\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}  \frac{(2yt)^i}{i!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} H_k(x) \frac{t^k}{k!}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now collect the $t^n$ terms and we have the result
\begin{eqnarray*}
H_n(x+y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} H_k(x) (2y)^{n-k}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick proof. To be honest I am asking this question on the behalf of a friend. I just confirmed that he knew the proof but search for a reference ( like a known formula/ table book, or a paper) where this formula is listed to include it in a brief paper he is writing. Thank you again.

Comment: My first suggestion for a ref would be wiki (you have already put this in your question) another good place to look is Wolfram alpha ... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html

Comment: You certainly have a point though some scholars have some reservation about using internet wikis as a reference in a peer-reviewed paper.